# Como acceder a datos de Session en CodeIgniter 4 desde la vista

Tags: codeigniter, php7, codeigniter-4

Hola estoy tratando de comenzar a trabajar con CI4, en CI3 podia acceder a la session desde la vista directamente. Ejemplo para pintar el nombre del usuario simplemente podia hacer esto y ya:

```php
echo $this->session->userdata('nombre')
```

Con CI 4, solo lo he logrado iniciando la session en cada vista:

```php
$session = \Config\Services::session($config);
```

Existe una manera global para manejo de sessiones?

Answer (score 0):

Las sesiones se ejecutan globalmente con cada carga de página, por lo que la clase Session debería ser inicializada por arte de magia.

En **CI4** para poder acceder a la **session** ahora se puede hacer de las siguientes maneras:

Arreglo de **session**:

```
$_SESSION['item']
```

Método convencional:

```
$session->get('item');
```

Receptor mágico:

```
$session->item
```

**Helper** de **session**:

```
session('item');
```

Para inicializar en caso de que no se cargue por automática la **session**, lo puedes hacer con:

```
$session = \Config\Services::session($config);
$session->start();
```

Para más información acerca de **session** puedes verificar la [documentación](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/sessions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Coloca esto dentro de tu vista, deseable en la zona superior de tu código

```
<?php $session = session(); ?>
```